# Accessing a private array when I have an extension method

Tags: c#, array, properties

I'm trying to make a number of data classes for my C#/XNA game, which would essentially be a wrapper around `T[,]`:

```
public interface IGrid<T>
    where T : struct
{
    Point Size { get; }
    T this[int x, int y] { get; set; }
}
```

For example, I might have a Heightmap object which is essentially an `IGrid<float>`, or I might have a Level.TileData object which is an `IGrid<byte>` or `IGrid<int>`. These could be entirely separate classes with specific helper methods, etc.

I also made a small extension library that operates specifically on any 2-dimensional array:

```
public static class Transformations
{
    static T[,] Transpose(this T[,] value);
    static T[,] FlipHorizontal(this T[,] value);
    static T[,] FlipVertical(this T[,] value);
    static T[,] RotateClockwise(this T[,] value);
    static T[,] RotateCounterClockwise(this T[,] value);
}
```

However, when I actually implement `IGrid<T>`, I encounter a small design issue.

Because the backing array would be private/protected, any client code that actually uses `IGrid<T>` would be unable to use my extension library.

According to [CA1819](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fss9skc(v=vs.100).aspx) and [Eric's blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20151121055235/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx), publicly exposing an array (even via properties!) is a bad idea, as it would be fully mutable. The suggested workaround is to clone the array, then expose it as an immutable type (which means I still don't have an array to use the library on).

Am I overthinking things, or is there an elegant solution here? I really like the idea of using indexers to read/write data on the object, but in some situations I *might* want to work with the entire array at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee that a client implementing `IGrid<T>` does actually use an 2D array `T[,]` for the implementation. So without changing something, you cannot expect to make your extension library work "out of the box" on `IGrid<T>`. IMHO you have the following options:

- change (or extend) the interface of your `Transformation` class to use `IGrid<T>` as input instead of `T[,]`. This is probably the cleanest alternative, but I guess if you want to keep and maintain the `T[,]` variant, too, it will mean some code duplication in your extension library, since `T[,]` and `IGrid<T>` don't have a common interface.
- to avoid the code duplication, you could write a conversion method from `IGrid<T>` to `T[,]`, but this will have the drawback of making additional copies of the data. You could use this with my first suggestion to create adapter methods to avoid the code-duplication:

  ```
   T[,] Transpose(this IGrid<T> value)
   {
        return ConvertIGridToArray(value).Transpose();
   }
  ```
- extend `IGrid<T>` to provide access to underlying `T[,]`, with the drawback of loosing immutability (which forces any client to use a `T[,]` internally)

Currently, I don't see a way to avoid the code duplication *and* the additional copying *and* the loss of immutability all three - pick your choice.

Note that for big arrays, immutability maybe not the optimal design for your transformation operations, without immutability they could be implemented in-place, which is sometimes the better alternative, since it is less memory consuming. Note further that if you want your transformation methods work on something like an `Heightmap` class, they cannot deliver a new `Heightmap`  object directly, you will have to do some type conversion either. An in-place transformation would not have that problem, it could operate on the internal `T[,]` of the Heightmap object directly.

Comment: Well, having out laid out my options for me, I think the easiest solution would be to bump my Transformation class over to IGrid<>, and if I really need to pass the data around, I can still iterate it via Size and indexers.